# Counter giving random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, counter

I am trying to implement a program which will get the students to count from 1 - 10.

The following is the code I have:

Main class:

```
public class JavaLab5 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;

    public static void multipleThreads(int number) {
        StudentThread []st = new StudentThread[number];
        for (int loop = 0; loop < number;loop++) {
            st[loop] = new StudentThread();
            st[loop].start();
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] {
        multipleThreads(10);  
    } 
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    static int studentCounter = 1;
    String name;
    private static int count = 0;
    public static int instances = 0;

    // Getters
    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public  String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Setters
    /**
     *
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        if (JavaLab5.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     * Populates name with defaults
     */
    public Student() {
        instances++;
        this.name = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param name String with the name
    */
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     * @throws Throwable 
     */
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        //do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
    } 

    /**
     * @return 
     */
    public void getCounter() {
        count++;
        //return count;
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return this.name; 
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getSubjects() {
        return null;  
    }
}
```

Computer student class:

```
public class ComputerStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ComputerStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ComputerStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Computer Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "] " + name + ": "); 
    }
}
```

Science Student:

```
public class ScienceStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScienceStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ScienceStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Science Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    } 
}
```

Math student:

```
public class MathStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @param name
     */
    public MathStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    public MathStudent() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" MathStudent" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    }
}
```

Student Thread:

```
public class StudentThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run(){
        Student s[] = new Student[10];

        //Student Array containing different types of students
        s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
        s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
        s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
        s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
        s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
        s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
        s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
        s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
        s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
        s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");

        //Checking and looping till the count reaches 10
        //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
            //Checking and looping till the end of the student array
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(s[i].getSubjects() + " - " + "Count:");
                s[i].getCounter();
        }
        try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception at StudentThread.run: " + e);
        }
        }

}
```

The output of the current code gives:

```
MathStudent[12]-Smith:  - Count:
 MathStudent[28]-Smith:  - Count:2




 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:3




 MathStudent[20]-Smith:  - Count:4

 MathStudent[21]-Jack:  - Count:5

 MathStudent[16]-Smith:  - Count:6

 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:7

 MathStudent[36]-Smith:  - Count:8

 MathStudent[24]-Smith:  - Count:9

 MathStudent[25]-Jack:  - Count:10

 MathStudent[26]-Victor:  - Count:11

 MathStudent[27]-Mike:  - Count:12

 Science Student[52]-Dave:  - Count:13
 MathStudent[37]-Jack:  - Count:14

 MathStudent[38]-Victor:  - Count:15

 MathStudent[39]-Mike:  - Count: MathStudent[29]-Jack:  - Count:17

1

 MathStudent[13]-Jack:  - Count:18

 MathStudent[14]-Victor:  - Count:19

 MathStudent[30]-Victor:  - Count:20

 MathStudent[32]-Smith:  - Count:21

 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:22

 MathStudent[33]-Jack:  - Count:23

 MathStudent[31]-Mike:  - Count:24

 MathStudent[15]-Mike:  - Count:25

 Science Student[64]-Dave:  - Count:26

 Science Student[65]-Oscar:  - Count:27

 Science Student[66]-Peter:  - Count:28

16
 Computer Student[67] Philip:  - Count:29


 MathStudent[4]-Victor:  - Count:30

 MathStudent[17]-Jack:  - Count:31

 MathStudent[18]-Victor:  - Count:32

 MathStudent[19]-Mike:  - Count:33

 MathStudent[22]-Victor:  - Count:34

 MathStudent[8]-Smith:  - Count:35

 MathStudent[9]-Jack:  - Count:36

 MathStudent[10]-Victor:  - Count:37

 MathStudent[11]-Mike:  - Count:38

 MathStudent[23]-Mike:  - Count:39

 Science Student[61]-Dave:  - Count:40

 MathStudent[6]-Mike:  - Count:41

 Science Student[46]-Dave:  - Count:42

 Science Student[53]-Oscar:  - Count:43

 Computer Student[70] Shaun:  - Count:44

 Computer Student[73] Scott:  - Count:45

 Science Student[55]-Dave:  - Count:46

 Science Student[56]-Oscar:  - Count:47

 MathStudent[34]-Victor:  - Count:48

 MathStudent[35]-Mike:  - Count:49

 Science Student[41]-Dave:  - Count:50

 MathStudent[3]-Jack:  - Count:51

 Science Student[43]-Oscar:  - Count:52

 Science Student[44]-Peter:  - Count:53

 Science Student[57]-Peter:  - Count:54

 Science Student[49]-Dave:  - Count:55

 Science Student[50]-Oscar:  - Count:56

 Science Student[51]-Peter:  - Count:57

 Computer Student[97] Philip:  - Count:58

 Computer Student[98] Shaun:  - Count:59

 Computer Student[99] Scott:  - Count:60
 Science Student[54]-Peter:  - Count:61

 Computer Student[88] Philip:  - Count:62

 Computer Student[89] Shaun:  - Count:63

 Computer Student[90] Scott:  - Count:64
 Science Student[47]-Oscar:  - Count:65

 Science Student[48]-Peter:  - Count:66

 Computer Student[76] Philip:  - Count:67

 Computer Student[77] Shaun:  - Count:68

 Computer Student[78] Scott:  - Count:69
 Science Student[62]-Oscar:  - Count:70

 Science Student[63]-Peter:  - Count:71

 Computer Student[79] Philip:  - Count:72

 Computer Student[80] Shaun:  - Count:73

 Science Student[58]-Dave:  - Count:74

 Science Student[59]-Oscar:  - Count:75

 Science Student[60]-Peter:  - Count:76

 Science Student[68]-Dave:  - Count:77

 Computer Student[82] Philip:  - Count:78

 Computer Student[81] Scott:  - Count:79
 Computer Student[85] Philip:  - Count:80

 Computer Student[86] Shaun:  - Count:81

 Computer Student[94] Philip:  - Count:82

 MathStudent[5]-Victor:  - Count:83

 Computer Student[95] Shaun:  - Count:84

 Computer Student[87] Scott:  - Count:85
 Computer Student[83] Shaun:  - Count:86

 Science Student[69]-Oscar:  - Count:87

 Computer Student[84] Scott:  - Count:88
 Computer Student[96] Scott:  - Count:89
 MathStudent[7]-Mike:  - Count:90

 Science Student[71]-Peter:  - Count:91

 Science Student[40]-Dave:  - Count:92

 Science Student[42]-Oscar:  - Count:93

 Computer Student[72] Philip:  - Count:94

 Science Student[45]-Peter:  - Count:95

 Computer Student[91] Philip:  - Count:96

 Computer Student[74] Shaun:  - Count:97

 Computer Student[92] Shaun:  - Count:98

 Computer Student[93] Scott:  - Count:99
 Computer Student[75] Scott:  - Count:100
```

As you can see the current output gives a randon count values and random student values which I don't understand why.

The output that I require is:

```
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:2
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:2
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:2
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:2
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:2
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:2
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:2
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:2
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:2
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:2
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:3
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:3
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:3
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:3
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:3
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:3
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:3
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:3
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:3
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:3
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:4
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:4
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:4
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:4
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:4
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:4
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:4
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:4
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:4
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:4
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:5
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:5
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:5
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:5
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:5
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:5
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:5
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:5
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:5
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:5
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:6
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:6
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:6
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:6
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:6
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:6
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:6
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:6
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:6
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:6
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:7
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:7
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:7
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:7
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:7
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:7
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:7
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:7
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:7
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:7
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:8
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:8
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:8
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:8
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:8
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:8
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:8
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:8
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:8
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:8
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:9
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:9
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:9
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:9
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:9
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:9
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:9
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:9
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:9
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:9
 MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:10
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:10
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:10
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:10
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:10
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:10
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:10
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:10
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:10
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:10
```

Why is the output printing out the random count values and random student numbers and how I can I fix this?

Comment: You need to synchronize updates to counters you share between threads, or use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: You could fix it yourself by following the guidance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the process of minimizing your example you would no doubt find the problem.

Comment: When do you expect this loop to end? `for (int loop = 0; loop < number;) { ... }`

Comment: @Andreas when the end of the array is reached.

Comment: @madman123 Why would it ever stop when `loop` will never be anything other than `0`?

Comment: @Andreas I get what you are saying, I have fixed that but still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

count and StudentCounter are static variables. Therefore, they are updated by all of the student objects. You start 10 and and instanciate 10 students in each thread. Each of these 100 student instances update these variables, which are shared among all of the instances since they were declared static.

Comment: But if i dont declare it static it just makes the student number 1 for all of the students, doesn't increment.

Comment: You should create an id field in your student object and assign it when at creation or after.

Comment: Don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem Java provides AtomicInteger, witch performs Integer operations in an atomic way.

Simply replace your static int variables for AtomicInteger and then use the methods of the class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html